# How to implement ESB in SOA architecture?

Tags: architecture, esb, soa

I'm expecting some ideas, especially the technologies currently available and implementation techniques. in simple words, Do I have to register ESB somewhere in service registries (third party) or just create one layer on top of the service layer and mentioned as the ESB...?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

your question is valid although too open. First let me clarify something.
SOA is a big big term that is part of an even bigger term called Service Oriented Computing.

You make SOA in a way to have service oriented software. It is a software architecture.

Today 2019 SOA is an option for enterprise that involves use of SOAP or REST web services, Service registries, Object oriented programming languages, Messaging systems, etc. I suggest you check MSA Micro Services Architecture (docker containers, Kubernetes, Cloud Computing, etc, etc)

A good starting point to understand SOA is Arcitura SOA. Please check the ESB pattern used to make a form of SOA at [arcitura ESB pattern](https://patterns.arcitura.com/soa-patterns/compound_patterns/enterprise_service_bus)